# Performing spectral unmixing fusion?

Tags: qgis, r, envi, fusion, spectrum-spatial-analyst

How can I perform a spectral unmixing fusion ?

The process consists on using a fraction image of a sensor "A" to obtain the reflectance image of a sensor "B", basically the inverse processes of spectral unmixing.

The spectral unmixing assumes that reflectance at each pixel of an image is a combination of the reflectance of each material (endmember) present within the pixel. A linear spectral unmixing, uses endmemembers in order to decompose a reflectance source spectrum into a set of given endmember spectra.

I succesfully used Envi or SPRING softwares in order to perform the spectral unmixing. Although, I don't know how to do the inverse process: use the fraction images to generate the reflectance image, since the softwares I used did not provide a transformation equation.